# Differential equation-unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I hope you can help me solve the following exercise...
$$x'''(t)-x(t)=0$$
If we know: $x(0)=1, x'''(0)=0 $
are these initial values enough for an initial value problem at t$\epsilon [0,1]$ with unique solution???

Comment: Don't you mean $x(0)=1, x''(0)=0$?

Comment: Are you sure those are the initial values you want? They obviously contradict the equation, since at zero it gives $0 - 1 = 0$.

Comment: If you mean $x''(0) = 0$, then the answer is no, you need another initial value.

Comment: $\LaTeX$ tip: use "\in", not "\epsilon".  For a third-order equation, you need three initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If $x'''(t)-x(t)=0$ for every $t$ in $[0,1]$, $x(0)=1$ and $x'''(0)=0$, then $x'''(0)-x(0)=-1$ hence $-1=0$. Starting from $-1=0$, one can prove anything.